# SystemVerilog register design race avoidance

Tags: scheduling, system-verilog, race-condition, digital-design

While doing digital design in systemverilog, I ran into an issue regarding racing conditions.

The test-bench (which I cannot modify) that drives my design, drives the inputs in such a way that certain registers in the design do not function properly due to a race condition.

Here is an eda-playground example which illustrates what is happening (input changes "before" the clock does, at time 15ns):

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/rWJ

Is there a way to make the design (a simple register in this case) resistant to this particular problem? What I need is a statement like "out_data <= preponed(in_data);" or something similar which will make the order of input signal changes irrelevant.

I have read about #1step in the SystemVerilog LRM but I am unsure how to use it, nor if it can help me with this particular problem at all.

Comment: The clock generator is written badly in the first place. It should have been `clock = ~clock`, with **blocking** assignment there. Also, if your inputs and the clock change at the same time, what kind of behavior would you expect?

Comment: I agree, but the clock generator is written badly on purpose, to illustrate how a race condition can occur in the design. If the two change at the same time, then I would expect the register output to obtain the value which the input signal had before any changes.

Comment: There is no good way to avoid a race which was artificially created by the test bench without fixing the latter. You would need to make your dut non-synthesizable to try otherwise. i.e. adding a #1ns delay to your in_data

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Serge I'm not sure if delays will make the design non-synthesizable. Tools might just ignore them.

Comment: Yes, which make their behavior after synthesis different from simulation. In this sense it is not really synthesizable and you will get warnings or errors from synthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test bench is essentially creating stimulus that is in a setup violation to your register. You have two options:

1. Convince the testbench writer of their erroneous ways and get them to fix it.
2. Insert a layer of hierarchy around the design that delays the clock to eliminate the race.